# "Buried alive", "burned alive"

Tags: american-english

> He is **buried alive**

or

> He is **burned alive**.

Is the word **"alive"** an adjective? In such a case, it's more likely an adverb.

Comment: So it seems.  But you could think of it as short for buried _while he was alive_. That way, the _phrase_ is adverbial, but "alive" remains an adjective.

Comment: Not the way of burying or burning is alive, "alive" refers to the victim's state. I call this adjective in adverb position. If you study this problem you can easily find 50 to 100 instances.

Answer (score 1):

In a few cases, an adjective can follow a transitive or passive verb, and be applied to object of that verb (or subject, if it's a passive verb). *Alive* is almost the only adjective I can think of examples for, but I think there are others possible.

> Njál Þorgeirson *was burned alive* by his enemy, Flosi Þórðarson.

A cornered outlaw may defy his pursuers:

> You'll never *take me alive*, [police]!

Or a criminal can be *caught red-handed*, if discovered in the act of his crime.

Answer (score 1):

Alive, as opposed to being dead, means that you're still living, breathing and doing all other biological activities typical of living organisms. To be buried alive means that you are put in the grave while you're not yet dead.

The thing about the word alive is that it can be used both as an adjective and in an adverbial type of fashion. Which one exactly it is being used as depends on how you use it in a sentence. Here are a bunch of examples to clarify that:

> — Is he still **alive**? *(adjective)*
>   — Yes, he is. He's weak, but he's doing all he can to cling to life. The guy's a real trooper!
>
> — He was buried **alive**. *(adverbial-type of usage)*
>   — How was he buried?
>   — He was buried **alive**. They thought he was dead. But no, it turned out that he was still breathing.

"He was buried alive" is similar in spirit to how we would use other adjectives with verbs that can often take an adjective and make it sound like an adverb. Among them are the verbs "to act" and "to come":

> He **acted innocent**, but that was all a lie. He was the guilty one.
>
> All the command-line tools that you'll ever need **come preinstalled** on every Linux distribution.

Although "innocent" and "preinstalled" are definitely not adverbs, the verbs "act" and "come" have this ability to make them sound and feel like they are.